# Httpclient response doesn't send

Tags: c#, rest, httpclient

I have a problem with my app. In my computer everything work good. I have problem with app on my notebook. I must debug app but my response doesn't work, this is Exception `The operation was canceled`. Api work, because i tested in PostMan. My code:

```cs
 if (httpClient != null)
                {
                    Task<string> response = httpClient.GetStringAsync($"myUrl");

                    string res = response.GetAwaiter().GetResult();

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(res))
                    {
                        myModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model>(res);
                    }
                }
```

somebody know why i have a problem on notebook?

Comment: `string res = await response;`

Comment: Is`$"myUrl"` is pointing to correct URL? Also why are you not using await for `GetStringAsync` call? Another point - any proxy setting on your notebook which is not allowing to set the request?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov why work in diffrent computer?

Comment: @user1672994  i told, url work, but in app i have a problem

Comment: intention to ask about `$"myUrl"` --- Should this not be `$"{myUrl}"` if `myUrl` is a variable defined in your code?

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: this is for example because i have const ip for debug and my code is ```${Url}/api/category```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to the following:

```
 if (httpClient != null)
{
     string response = await httpClient.GetStringAsync($"myUrl");

     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(response ))
     {
        myModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model>(response);
     }
}
```

No need to use [GetAwaiter()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.getawaiter?view=net-5.0)

> This method is intended for compiler use rather than for use in application code.

You need to await in async calls, in order to execute the actual call.

Comment: What's wrong? What is the issue with this code?